# Can I create new objects in Vue data() function?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating a `new Audio()` object inside a Vue component's `data() { ... }` function, but I got concerned about if this is unnecessarily creating more Audio objects.

I can't seem to find when or how the data() function is called, but I also couldn't find any examples that crates a new object in the data function.

Is it ok to create new objects inside `data()` ? Or should I leave those initializations to the `created()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation about data() : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

> a component’s data option must be a function, so that each instance can maintain **an independent copy** of the returned data object.

It is the right way to do it.

Your new object will be instantiated like so :

```js
data() {
  // new object returned
  return {
    audio: new Audio()
  }
}
```

If you want to have a global object to avoid multiple instance of `audio`, think about attaching it to the global Vue instance or using Vuex depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely fine to create new objects inside the returned object of the `data()` function, that's what is meant for. More informations [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).